# Windows DHCP/DNS/AD - Retrieve/Store/Manage IP Addresses

Tags: windows, automation, ipam

We're using a windows 2012 R2 server as DHCP/DNS/AD. I would like to use a tool, that enables me to retrieve every IP addresses that are in use, and DNS register and/or hostnames associated with. Plus, would be great if it can automatically discover if there is something new.

I thought using IPAM from Microsoft, but unfortunately it does not populate automatically...

Is the best way the following : Writing several scripts (PowerShell) that retrieve DHCP/DNS/AD informations, and store it as an html file ?

I'm sure you guys, know a basic tool that does the job.

Tia.

Comment: You mean you want a dump of the leases within the scopes of your DHCP server(s)?

Comment: Not only, I know this can be achieve with Get-DHCPv4lease (or smth similar).  I would like to retrieve static ip (using DNS, or DHCP reservation) and hostnames, but also all free IPs. I'm having a look at GestioIP and using PS scripts to do some SQL requests. Do you know if GestioIP has a great integration within M$ environment ?

Comment: So this looks like reporting purposes. You could tailor-script this to your needs, but I am not quite sure what you're missing from IPAM, though. It obviously does populate automatically by querying DHCP and DNS servers in the forest - that's the whole point. I never have had any contact with GestioIP, so I can't tell much about its AD integration capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for answering. IPAM does not retrieve static IP or reservation, or DNS records. Or mb I'm totally wrong. And this is not programatically

Comment: Well, it should. And IPAM has a PowerShell scripting interface. You might want to open another question on IPAM, if you had any issues with getting meaningful report data out of it in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'll test out things, and comeback if I found anything interesting or any alternative solution. Thanks @the-wabbit